# ChartJS number shows up on top of number

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For a project I made something in chartjs that looked something to this: https://jsfiddle.net/ethernetz/e50fn31m/2/

I had to do some digging around on the internet to get a number to show up in the middle of the doughnut graph, but that was exactly what I wanted. Then I wanted to make a second doughnut graph, which made the project looks something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ethernetz/4uw1ksu1/

As you can see, the "60" from the completion graph shows up on top of the "40" from the incompletion graph and vice versa.

I suspect it has to do with me never specifying what graph I want to edit here:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        var width = chart.chart.width,
            height = chart.chart.height,
            ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
```

...but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change the following line of code in your plugin :**

```
var text = 60;
```

**to this :**

```
var text = chart.id == 0 ? 60 : 40;
```

basically, when a chart is created, it is assigned an **`id`** *(0 based)*. so you need to set the text based on that chart-id.

also, there­*'s* no need to add two separate plugins, as you are creating a global plugin, which will be applied to all of your charts.

Here is the [**working example on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2p7rx9bg/)

Answer (score 0):

use only one "chart.pluginService.register" for all charts, because it subscribes to the chart class, so mychart and mychart2 belong to chart class, then don't use the callback "chart"... use mychart and mychart2 instead of callback to recognize each chart registered.

new code:

```
var charts = [{
            current: myChart
              , text: 60
              }, {
            current: myChart2
              , text: 40
              }];

Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: function(chart) {
            for (var iterator of charts) {
                var width = iterator.current.chart.width,
                    height = iterator.current.chart.height,
                    ctx = iterator.current.chart.ctx;
                    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                        //ctx.restore(); dont clear, this delete the previous chart, drawing only text
                var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
                ctx.font = fontSize + "em lato";
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.85)"
                ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
                var text = iterator.text,
                            textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                            textY = height / 2.5;
                ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
                ctx.save();
        }
    }
});
```

updated jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4uw1ksu1/2/